# Animation doesn't doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Here's my animation xml code

```
<rotate
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:duration="2500"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    />
```

Here's my kotlin code

```
private fun animateSidebarOpener() {
    val rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sidebar_button_animation)
    binding?.btnOpenSidebar?.animation = rotate
}
```

Thing is that for the animation to work, I need to start another activity and close it for the animation to work, how to make it work as soon as I  call the `animateSideBarOpener` function

Comment: Calling the function in `onResume()` triggered the rotation just fine... Please add enough code (a [MCVE]) to enable us to reproduce your situation

Comment: what's the onResume()

Comment: [Activity.onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onResume())

Comment: You've got me wrong, it doesn't work in onCreate, it works in onResume? got it?